Text extracted from Pdfminer python library is empty but the length of text is not 0
I have a python code in which I am trying to read the contents of various pdf files-scanned and text based both using pdfminer , the code is like this:
``with open(os.path.join(pdf_directory, file_name), 'rb') as file: 
                
                output_string = StringIO()

                parser = PDFParser(file)
                doc = PDFDocument(parser)
                rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
                device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, output_string, laparams=LAParams())
                interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
                for page in PDFPage.create_pages(doc):
                    interpreter.process_page(page)
                text=output_string.getvalue()
                if len(text)==0:
                    
                    
                    extract_ocr(pdf_directory,file_name,text_directory)``

Where extract_ocr is a different function where ocr-processing for scanned pdf is done, the code is failing as the text extracted from it is indeed empty but the len(text)==0 condition is not satisfied as len(text)!=0 , this condition was working earlier when i was using pypdf2 instead of pdfminer, any suggestions how to tackle this condition?

How have you verified that text is empty and does contain any (incl. whitespace) characters?

Hi i printed the text, it is empty lines on terminal

Doesn't mean it's empty.

Yeah I know it's empty to the eye but not to the program that's why my condition is failing

Have you print(repr(text)), what do you see?

PDFs in the wild have lots of quirks. But I understand that you have used pypdf2 earlier and you got null strings. Probably they preprocessed the text before returning it to you. The simplest possible solution might be to check by stripping the text.
Change if len(text)==0: to if len(text.strip())==0:
I have worked with a lot of PDF files and there is no easy way to determine whether a PDF is a text based PDF or a scanned PDF. It becomes even more difficult with "searchable" PDFs which are scanned PDFs with a text overlay for enabling search. Of course if you have control over the type of PDFs you are processing, it is not a issue. I am talking about PDFs in the wild.
